# Re-enter USA, forgot I797

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, h1b-visas

I’m on the H1b visa. Currently traveling internationally but heading back to the USA in the next couple of days. I’ve forgotten my form I797 but have access to a photocopy, and of course I have my passport with the H1B stamp on it.

Would I have any problems reentering the USA without the original I797?

Comment: I don't know the technical legalities, but anecdotally I can say that I've re-entered the USA a number of times after travelling to various different countries (UK, South Africa, Canada, Costa Rica) over the last 5-6 years without needing to show my I-797. A valid, unexpired H-1B was all that I needed. What makes you think that you'd need your I-797?

Comment: Because I have been asked for it on other occasions at the Port of Entry

Comment: Interesting - maybe I'm just lucky.